# Range based slicing with the get and set index functions?

Tags: julia

How can I allow for range based slicing with the get and set index functions?

And will they be copies or views? views are preferable.

```
function Base.getindex(cb::CircularMatrix, I::Vararg{Int,2})
    cb.buffer[I[1], _buffer_index_checked(cb, I[2])]
end

function Base.setindex!(cb::CircularMatrix, data, I::Vararg{Int,2})
    cb.buffer[I[1], _buffer_index_checked(cb, I[2])] = data
    cb
end

s = CircluarMatrix{Int}(5, 5)
s[:, 5]
s[5, :]
```

Comment: Just define `CircularMatrix` as a subtype of `AbstractMatrix` and you'll get it for free.  Indexing with square brackets returns copies; use `view` or `@views` to get views.